# Why is NGINX treating requests differently, if their request urls are the same?

Tags: http, nginx

I can't figure out why one request is matched, yet the other is 404'd.

```
192.168.120.88 - - [04/Jan/2018:15:47:29 -0800] "GET /bender/next HTTP/1.1" 200 20 "http://192.168.36.10/bender/NextPanel" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36"
192.168.120.88 - - [04/Jan/2018:15:47:30 -0800] "GET /bender/next HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "http://localhost:8080/bender/NextPanel" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3310.0 Safari/537.36"
```

I took these `/var/log/nginx/access.log`

The request from localhost is being sent by a webpack dev server proxy, while the other is being sent from a production client.

```
    location ^~ /bender/partimages { 
            proxy_set_header Host $host; 
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 
            proxy_pass http://192.168.36.6:9008/; 
    } 


    location ^~ /bender/ { 
            proxy_set_header Host $host; 
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 
            proxy_pass http://192.168.36.3:9008/; 
    }
```

This is the relevant part of my config file. The only thing different between the requests is the hosts, and chrome version.  Can these things effect the match?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your `Host` header in `webpack-dev-server` [option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-headers-) to `192.168.36.10`

Answer (score 0):

I had accidentally set webpack's dev server to proxy the request over https, which NGINX wasn't configured to handle.